# Obtengo simbolos en lugar de texto con Crawler en Laravel

Tags: laravel, guzzle

tengo un problema con este crawler, pongo la url y me sale todos los datos sin problema, pero el blog esta en español... y el texto que me sale es:

"Hoy en d\u00eda es posible encontrar en diversas tiendas, tanto on-line como f\u00edsicas"
y el texto original debería ser: "Hoy en día es posible encontrar en diversas tiendas, tanto on-line como físicas"

se cambian las letras á é í o ú
este código:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/';
        
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', $url);
        $html = (string) $response->getBody();

        $crawler = new Crawler($html);
$title = $crawler->filter('h1')->text();
$content = $crawler->filter('div.content-inner')->text();

$links = $crawler->filter('.blog-post-title a')->each(function ($node) {
            return $node->attr('href');
        });

return response()->json([
            'titles' => $title,
            'links' => $links,
            'content' =>$content
        ]);
```

como se puede solucionar esto?